# Reading Excel from src folder using JXL

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am a beginner and having a hard time to get my program run correctly after exporting it as runnable JAR.

I need to read an Excel called "bstn.xls", which is in the dDefault package such as all other classes.
Here is how I did it.

1. get the file path with: `URL excelURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bstn.xls");`
2. Create a File with the URL `File file = new File(new ResourceLoader().loader());`
3. Create a workbook with the file `wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);`

I got the error in german here, but it says: the System cannot find the given path.
Is JXL not able to read with the full qualified path? I can't find anything on the JXL site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is in the classpath, you may use the [getWorkbook](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)) method taking an `InputStream` parameter :

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bstn.xls");
wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(stream);
```